# Is it possible to do N-master => 1-slave replication with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

I want to make a dedicated SLAVE machine for data replication of three database on three different servers.  In other words, I want to do Multiple Master => SIngle Slave replication.

Is there any way to do this, as simple as it can be ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Multi-master replication (a slave with more than one master) is not supported by MySQL (besides MySQL Cluster). You can do a master-master replication of a circular (ring) replication (described [here](http://capttofu.livejournal.com/1752.html) or [here](http://onlamp.com/onlamp/2006/04/20/advanced-mysql-replication.html)).

In [*High performance MySQL 2nd edition*](http://books.google.de/books?id=BL0NNoFPuAQC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_navlinks_s#v=onepage&q=&f=false) the authors describe a way to emulate multi-master replication using a clever combination of master-master replication and the [`Blackhole`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html) storage engine (Chapter 8 Replication > Replication Topologies > Custom Replication Solutions > Emulating multimaster replication p. [373 - 375](http://books.google.de/books?id=BL0NNoFPuAQC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA373#v=onepage&q=&f=false)).

They show two possibly topologies:

**Using two co-masters** (allowing to switch the master of the slave from **Master 1** to **Master 2**)

- **Master 1:** hosts *DB1* and replicates *DB2* from **Master 2**; the storage engine for all tables in *DB2* is changed to `Blackhole` so that the data is not effectively stored on **Master 1**.
- **Master 2:** hosts *DB2* and replicates *DB1* from **Master 1**; the storage engine for all tables in *DB1* is changed to `Blackhole` so that the data is not effectively stored on **Master 2**
- **Slave 1:** replicates *DB1* and *DB2* from either **Master 1** or **Master 2** (allowing to switch masters); the result is that **Slave 1** replicates both databases that are effectively hosted on two different masters.

**Using a master-chain**

- **Master 1:** only hosts *DB1*
- **Master 2:** hosts *DB2* and replicates *DB1* from **Master 1**; the storage engine for all tables in *DB1* is changed to `Blackhole` so that the data is not effectively stored on **Master 2**
- **Slave 1:** replicates *DB1* and *DB2* from **Master 2**; the result is that **Slave 1** replicates both databases that are effectively hosted on two different masters.

Please note that this setup only allows you to send updates to *DB1* through **Master 1** and updates to *DB2* to **Master 2**. You **cannot** send updates to either table to arbitrary masters.

Pehaps it's possible to combine the described solution with the hack for a true master-master replication (allowing updates to both masters) that uses some sort of autoincrement-mangling and is described [here](http://capttofu.livejournal.com/1752.html) or [here](http://onlamp.com/onlamp/2006/04/20/advanced-mysql-replication.html).

Answer (score 0):

No way that I'm aware of.

However, if the requirement here is simply to have a single replication-based backup machine, you can easily enough run three MySQL servers (on different addresses and/or ports) - we do that here, with two replication rings that each include our in-house staging server as a node.

An off-the-wall idea, if you really do want all the data into a single server and the table schemas are either fixed, or pretty much static and under your control: set up one server with the three databases on and link all the tables using the federated engine. In theory (huge caveat: I've never tried it!), you can then replicate off those federated tables on to a second server (again, possibly on the same machine), giving you genuine live copies of the data on a single MySQL instance. You could even try replicating back again, but that way possibly lies madness :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a lot about MySQL, but don't you have the possibility to set an 'upload only' replication configuration, where the role of the master/publisher is only to collect updates made at the slave/subscriber level.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth a look at [maatkit's table sync](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-sync.html) -- it's not "real" replication but it might be good enough.