# sync database between local and live, php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv, synchronization

I am working on a "point of sale" project, here's what i have:

1. i have a local database, maybe mysql db, csv file, or even xml file which store the data of customers.
2. i have a system database on my own server with full data.
3. after a specific period of time, i want to sync the data between local one and live database, to update or insert latest data.
4. if there's no internet, it will keep the offline data until internet is back and start sync again.

my questions are:

1. which local data type i should use (mysql db, csv file, xml file, or something else)?
2. how to manage a sync process like this?

Comment: Most likely not an option for you, but I always thought CouchDB is an interesting alternative database technology that would be ideal for POS systems. http://couchdb.apache.org/

Comment: thanks Mark O'Connor, first time to see couchdb :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the device hardware is able to run a MySQL server without performance issues then I would use MySQL on both the device and the server. This would save from translation between different data formats. Also you can benefit form MySQL's [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) capabilities.

Comment: it says that: "Replication enables data from one MySQL database server (the master) to be replicated to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves)." I want (slaves) to update the (master)

Comment: I created such a test scenario once. I can not 100% say that replication will do the job. (Will prepare a setup, just for interest). However, I would, with or without replication, use MySQL if you are free of choice as will save at least the translation overhead between different data formats

Comment: Read this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576603/is-it-possible-to-do-n-master-1-slave-replication-with-mysql) post

Comment: thanks a lot, but is there's another option you would suggest for me?

Comment: I see no reason for something different. Possible options you've already mentioned in the question. Why are you asking? Because of performance or license issues?

Comment: yes it's about performance, i want to do this with best performance as much as i can

Comment: It will depend on your application. One cannot give a general answer. If you want we can discuss in chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23178/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-sprince)